# HTML – Selecting multiple text in multiple frames

Tags: html, css, frames, textselection

Is it possible to instruct HTML / CSS to maintain selections separate in separate frames (or iframes, divs, or anything)?

I would need to separate the text selection mechanism in different frames. So, when I select a text in the first frame, then in a second, the first should remain selected. Furthermore, when I select again in the first, only the first selection should change, and the second should be preserved. Like in two separate windows.

(I would need it for a video / screen recording, so it is not a problem at all if the solution would not work in every browser, just under very specific circumstances, for example, with a certain extension of a certain browser, or advanced CSS version.)

Comment: I found this Javascript library with which in theory it would be possible, so long as it will remove all selection when selecting in same frame / div: https://github.com/mir3z/texthighlighter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I tried it with to iframes (instead of frames) in Chrome, and surprisingly it works without any additions.

Only by frames is the first frame deselected automatically when selecting in second frame. So problem solved for now!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to make complex javascripts to make this.
Just hold CTRL while selecting and select multiple text (works on Firefox, maybe on Chrome too). I hope this is a useful answer!
EDIT: as BinyominZeev said, use [github.com/mir3z/texthighlighter](http://github.com/mir3z/texthighlighter)

Comment: I thought about it. The problem is that when I select again in the first frame, the old selection in the first frame won't be removed. And there is no way (which I am aware of) that only one of the selections would remain and the other removed.